# Flask, Heroku and Github Dependencies/File Structure

Tags: python, heroku, github, dependencies, flask

Quite a beginner at the whole flask/heroku/github business, but been using python for several years now and had experience with tortoise SVN. I have been following the tutorial on how to push code to heroku at this link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python and after much tinkering I managed to get my web app uploaded. However I have definitely missed something.

Currently within the project I have a file structure to organize different processes (for example webservice calls and database handling), these are then imported into the main app by a code of the sort:

```
## Webservices
dirname, filename = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))
WSdirname = dirname + '\\WebServices\\'
sys.path.append(WSdirname)

import WebservicesModule as WSmodule # Module resides in "WebSerivices" folder
```

Which implies files are stored in a structure like

```
AppFolder\
    app.py
    WebServices\
        WebservicesModules.py
        ...
    Database\
        DatabaseModules.py
        ...
```

Locally this works. However once pushed by git to heroku it would seem that the code cannot access the `WebservicesModule` module. Giving an error in the form

> Import error: no module named WebservicesModule.

To explain why I have this file structure; as there will be a large number of webservices required it is easier to have them contained within the same folder. Similarly for the database operations and so forth.

My question is this. Is my code bad practice, meaning heroku doesn't allow it? Or has git hub not uploaded my files to heroku, hence not being able to find them (despite being in the file structure of the master directory)? Or is there some issue I don't know about? Do I need to declare these modules as dependencies in the requirements.txt, despite doing so in the code?

Cheers for any help you can provide :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that locally you are developing on Windows, while Heroku's slugs use some variant of Linux.  `\` is the directory separator on Windows but **`/`** is the directory separator on Linux.

Rather than hard-coding `\WebServices\` use `os.path.join` to join your path and subdirectories:

```
WSdirname = os.path.join(dirname, "WebServices")
```

That will ensure that no matter *what* platform you deploy to, the correct directory separator is used.